# How to get array values on radio checked in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm very new to Angularjs, started using today. And my first task is to convert some simple price calculation form jQuery to Angularjs.

I have 3 groups of options containing 2 radio inputs each . In jQuery I made a set of nested `if` statements as price is depended on the radios. Please, see the fiddle for details https://jsfiddle.net/nhx3aqeL/9/

I started the move to Angularjs by using `ng-repeat` for products output. And I have a set of prices in the array of the products' scope.

My question is: how to get values from that array on certain radio button being checked and make the price depended on the checked set of radios?

Comment: OMG! What's with all that jQuery?

Comment: Hahaha, that's the reason I need to convert it to Angular: combining business with pleasure. Wanted to simplify the code, and realised, that it's good reason to learn something new.

Comment: Attach you existing html markup and jquery in a fiddle so that we can understand what you are trying to reproduce in Angular and suggest accordingly.

Comment: The question contains a link to fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nhx3aqeL/9/